# Opencv show black image in this image but and another with small size it is works

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I edited and write my problem more succinctrly. I have this algorithm (in MATLAB) for a problem:

```
Require: Multivariable image (im) of size $n_1n_2 \times d$, the preorder (h_function) is a vector with $n_1n_2$ components and structuring element (se).

[.,b] = sort(h_function);

im_latt(b) = 1:(n1n2);

im_latt = reshape(im_latt, n1, n2);

im_ero = Erode(im_latt,SE);

im_out = reshape(im(b(im_ero(:)),:), n1, n2, d);
```

I am trying to make this program in Python.
My figure that has the name "fig01" has a body (512, 768, 3), that is, n1 = 512, n2 = 768 and d = 3.
Already with a lot of struggle and help I managed to create the program

```
import CV2 as CV
import numpy as np
matplotlib import pyplot as plt


im = cv.imread ("fig01.png", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
im = cv.cvtColor (im, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB) / 255

n1, n2, d = im.shape
vet = im.reshape(n1*n2, d)
def h_function(vet):
    return np.mean(vet,axis=1)
vet_h = h_function(vet)
im_h = vet_h.reshape(n1,n2)
b = np.argsort(vet_h).reshape(vet_h.shape)
im_latt = np.zeros(vet_h.shape, np.uint8)
im_latt[b] = range(0,n1*n2)
im_latt = im_latt.reshape((n1,n2))
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
im_ero = cv.erode(im_latt, kernel, iterations = 1)
ind = b[im_ero.reshape(vet_h.shape)]
im_out=vet[ind,:].reshape((n1,n2,d))
```

My problem is that the figure has totally black.

PS: My experience with Python is still only one week and I have studied on this site opencv.org. I installed the Anaconda Navigator and I am using Jupyter and Open Python 3.

PS2.: I searched on this site [opencv show black image after numpy vectorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224003/opencv-show-black-image-after-numpy-vectorize) about my problem and I managed to get close to this problem and this solution. But I couldn't understand.

PS3. (edit) I tried to let more clear my code and question.

Comment: I think your first has an extra parentheses here: `im_op = cv.erode (im_latt, np.ones ((3,3), np.uint32)), iterations = 1)`. There should only be one parentheses after `np.uint32`, otherwise `iterations = 1` won't be included in the function call

Comment: @awarrier99 thanks! But I tried the same code with a short image and this code works. But with this image not. And I took a parenthesis after np.uint32 and it didn't work. I will try again.

Comment: Hello Samuel, I will give you some tips on making your question more likable for the readers: (1)  Nobody likes to read a lot, try to only add the things needed to answer your question. (2) It seems that you get some errors before you try something new, you could try to fix that error, Usually, a solution/explanation to the error can be found by putting the error directly into google. If no explanation or solution is found, you can ask a question on StackOverflow on why it happens, what it means and how do you fix it. (3) Generalize, instead of asking how to specifically fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @OuuGiii. As you can see, I am a beginner on this platform. Although I researched my problem and tried to read about the rules of this environment, I did what was necessary to make my problem clear and try not to write too much. In the next questions I ask with you tipss, however, in this particular one, I don't know how to generalize the problem. In fact, I already found a similar problem with your proposed solution as in the link above and in the meantime I was unable to solve my type of problem. Also, the indicated solution regarding whether or not to add parentheses did not work.

Comment: I understand, good work (Y) But it is still a bit unclear what you are asking about. Do you want. Do you want to know why the errors are happening? Do you want to know why the image is black? Or do you only want to know how to show an image in OpenCV?

Another question, are the errors occurring when the black image occurs?

And maybe you could add to the title that what kind of image you try to show, as it seems to be the correct question.

My earlier tips where to general and probably didn't help. Hope this comment helps you more.

Comment: Thanks @OuuGiii. I'd like to understand why the errors are happening since in a smaller image the code above works. I don't know how to answer your last question. I will rewrite my code all over again, line by line, to try to find the error or even try to answer your question.

Comment: @OuuGiii, I think that has become clearer now. The problem persists.

Comment: So no error occurs now? If no, it is a better question. Please change the title of the question to something like "How to create this [INPUT_ALGORITHM_NAME] in Python/OpenCV". Because it seems like you now can show the image, but the algorithm is wrong.

Comment: In my opinion the algorithm is correct, but the image does not appear. It goes all black.